# RODBC sqlSave() and mapping column names

Tags: r, rodbc

I've a question about using sqlSave. How does R map RODBC data in the data frame to the database table columns?

If I've a table with columns X and Y and a data frame with columns X and Y, RODBC puts X into X and Y into Y (I found out by trail-and-error). But can I explicitly tell R how to map data.frame columns to database table columns, like put A in X and B in Y.

I'm rather new to R and think the RODBC manual is a bit cryptic. Nor can I find an example on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm now doing it this way (maybe that's also what you meant):

```
colnames(dat) <- c("A", "B")
sqlSave(channel, dat, tablename = "tblTest", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

It works for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That alters the object before saving it which, while getting the job done,  is not what you asked for.

Comment: Sure, but the altered object is only temporarily, so it's no problem

Answer (score 1):

You should find the fine R manuals of great help as you start to explore R, and its help facilities are very good too.

If you start with

```
  help(sqlSave)
```

you will see the `colNames` argument. Supplying a vector `c("A", "B")` would put your first data.frame column into a table column A etc.

Comment: What do you mean with "its help facilities"? I use http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf. But that document speaks about the "colnames" argument as "logical: save column names as the ﬁrst row of table?", not as a vector suppling columnNAMES

Comment: Still the "colnames" argument is a logical

Comment: It should be noted that as of RODBC-1.3.13, the only reference to `colnames` in the source of `sqlSave` is in a single comparison: ` if (is.logical(colnames) && colnames)` (and the subsequent block within that if statement), suggesting that a character vector won't work (anymore?). (Perhaps the behavior has changed over the years, \*shrug\*.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having massive problems using `sqlSave` with an IBM DB2 databank. I'm trying to avoid it by using `sqlQuery` instead to create the table with the correct formatting and then use `sqlSave` with `append=T` to force my R table into the database table. This resolve a lot of problems such as date formats and floating point numbers (instead of doubles).